# Finding last index of repeating character string and relative frequency of character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a javascript problem for fun that is supposed to take a string and return nested arrays that contain one array for every character that repeats. The groups should have the following structure: `[[value, first_index, last_index, times_repeated], ..., [value, first_index, last_index, times_repeated]]`. With the current code I have the value and first index is always correct, but I am struggling to understand how I would find the last index of a character that is contained in a repeat, and also how to find the frequency of just that repeat.

- value: Character being assessed.
- first_index: Index of characters first appearance.
- last_index: Index of characters last appearance.
- times_repeated: Number of consecutive times character repeats.

Here is my code:

```
function findRepeating(str) {
const splitter = str.split("");
let arr = [];

const getOccurance = (array, value) => {
    let count = 0;
array.forEach((v) => (v === value && count++));
return count;
}

for(i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++){
    if(i === 0){
        let firstArr = [];
        firstArr.push(splitter[i], i, splitter.lastIndexOf(splitter[i]), getOccurance(splitter, splitter[i]));
        arr.push(firstArr);
    } else {
        if(splitter[i] !== splitter[i - 1]){
            let nArr = [];

            nArr.push(splitter[i], i, splitter.lastIndexOf(splitter[i]), getOccurance(splitter, splitter[i]));
            arr.push(nArr);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
return arr;
}
```

Here are some expected outputs based on string inputs:

```
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating(''), [])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('a'), [['a', 0, 0, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1337'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['3', 1, 2, 2], ['7', 3, 3, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('addressee'), [['a', 0, 0, 1], ['d', 1, 2, 2], ['r', 3, 3, 1], ['e', 4, 4, 1], ['s', 5, 6, 2], ['e', 7, 8, 2]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbbaabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3], ['a', 5, 6, 2], ['b', 7, 9, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1111222233334444'), [['1', 0, 3, 4], ['2', 4, 7, 4], ['3', 8, 11, 4], ['4', 12, 15, 4]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1000000000000066600000000000001'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['0', 1, 13, 13], ['6', 14, 16, 3], ['0', 17, 29, 13], ['1', 30, 30, 1]])
```

Comment: How complicated do you want your solution to be? Would a simpler solution be acceptable? For example, how about a straight loop that keeps track of things while comparing the current char to the last char looked at. When they differ, update the array.

Comment: Sure I'll take any solution if it solves it

Comment: Well if you use that idea, all you'd need is a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution which could solve it. The [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) method has a special replacement callback which you can use. You can pass it an argument of `/(.)\1*/g` which is a regular expression that matches groups of characters. The replacement method then gives the match (`m`, ie the group of characters), the single character it matched in the group `c`, and the index it was matched at `i`. Using all this, you can get all the information you need for your output:

```js
const findRepeating = str => {
  const res = [];
  str.replace(/(.)\1*/g, (m, c, i) => res.push([c, i, i+m.length-1, m.length]));
  return res;
}

Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating(''), [])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('a'), [['a', 0, 0, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1337'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['3', 1, 2, 2], ['7', 3, 3, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('addressee'), [['a', 0, 0, 1], ['d', 1, 2, 2], ['r', 3, 3, 1], ['e', 4, 4, 1], ['s', 5, 6, 2], ['e', 7, 8, 2]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbbaabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3], ['a', 5, 6, 2], ['b', 7, 9, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1111222233334444'), [['1', 0, 3, 4], ['2', 4, 7, 4], ['3', 8, 11, 4], ['4', 12, 15, 4]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1000000000000066600000000000001'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['0', 1, 13, 13], ['6', 14, 16, 3], ['0', 17, 29, 13], ['1', 30, 30, 1]]);
```

```html
<script>
  const Test = {
    assertSimilar: (res, arr) => {
      console.log(...(JSON.stringify(res) !== JSON.stringify(arr) ? ["Unexpected result:", res, "expected:", arr]: ["Test passed"]));
    }
  }
</script>
```

the above is a little hacky as it abuses `.replace()`, this can be done in a more conventional way with a modern method such as [`.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const findRepeating = str => 
  Array.from(str.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g), ({0: m, 1: c, index}) => [c, index, index+m.length-1, m.length]);

Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating(''), [])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('a'), [['a', 0, 0, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1337'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['3', 1, 2, 2], ['7', 3, 3, 1]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('addressee'), [['a', 0, 0, 1], ['d', 1, 2, 2], ['r', 3, 3, 1], ['e', 4, 4, 1], ['s', 5, 6, 2], ['e', 7, 8, 2]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('aabbbaabbb'), [['a', 0, 1, 2], ['b', 2, 4, 3], ['a', 5, 6, 2], ['b', 7, 9, 3]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1111222233334444'), [['1', 0, 3, 4], ['2', 4, 7, 4], ['3', 8, 11, 4], ['4', 12, 15, 4]])
Test.assertSimilar(findRepeating('1000000000000066600000000000001'), [['1', 0, 0, 1], ['0', 1, 13, 13], ['6', 14, 16, 3], ['0', 17, 29, 13], ['1', 30, 30, 1]]);
```

```html
<script>
  const Test = {
    assertSimilar: (res, arr) => {
      console.log(...(JSON.stringify(res) !== JSON.stringify(arr) ? ["Unexpected result:", res, "expected:", arr]: ["Test passed"]));
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a lovely shorthand version of what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I like your way too. Mine sort of abuses replace haha.

Comment: Awesome regex, replace combo. My code would have been a lot longer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex-based solution that uses a regex which looks for a repeated string of characters, capturing the character into group 1 and using the length of the match to update start and end pointers for the result:

```js
function findRepeating(str) {
  let result = [];
  let len, start = 0;
  let regex = /(.)\1*/g;
  while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    len = m[0].length;
    result.push([m[1], start, start + len - 1, len]);
    start = start + len;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(findRepeating('aabbbaabbb'));
```